ASP.NET Identity : ExpireTimeSpan at server not working
I used ASP.NET Identity and at this time have a problem.
My problem is that ExpireTimeSpan is not working at the server.
My Program code is
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(option => { option.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBaseContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

And Login Code :
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, true, true);

This code at localhost works without problem, only on the server I have this problem.
At server, after 4-5 hours is signed out.
Why?

You've only posted a single line of code with no context - so we can't help you because we have no idea when or where are you're passing ExpireTimeSpan to.

Could you please tell me how you host this application in the server? Inside the IIS or else? Is there any setting inside the server which will caused the cookie time expire quickly?

Code is added..

My host application is plesk

Ask plesk to help check for it.
